# jquerymobile - append results in duplicates when back button is pressed

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

i have 2 pages. Page 1 has the code attached below.

When i navigate to page 2 and press the back button, the code below on page 1 gets fired again and adds on to the div, which results in duplicates.

Any idea how i can prevent the duplicates from happening?

```js
  //load category data from category JSON and display
        $(document).on('pagebeforeshow', '#main', function() {
            $.getJSON("./json/category.json", function(data) {
                $.each(data, function(key, val) {
                    $('#category-cards').append("<div><a href='#' id='" + val.id + "'><div class='card'><div class='card-image'><img src='" + val.image + "'/><h2>" + val.name + "</h2></div></div></a>");
                });
            });
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

resolved by using pagecreate

```js
//load category data from category JSON and display
        $(document).on('pagecreate', '#main', function() {
            $.getJSON("./json/category.json", function(data) {
                $.each(data, function(key, val) {
                    $('#category-cards').append("<div><a href='#' id='" + val.id + "'><div class='card'><div class='card-image'><img src='" + val.image + "'/><h2>" + val.name + "</h2></div></div></a>");
                });
            });
        });
```